# Xamarin blank app errors

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2015

I am new to Xamarin, and I'm trying to set everything right. I already have Android Studio on my computer with SDK installed, also Android SDK Platform-tools installed via SDK manager (I read somewhere that as a solution to this problem, so it's worth to mention). SDK path is given to VS and it's valid.

Each time I try to create Xamarin.Forms PCL project, I get the same warnings:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.   MyTunes.Droid       1   Active


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'MyTunes.Shared, Version=, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'MyTunes.Shared.dll'
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(String fullName, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(String fullName)
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.GetAssembly(String fileName)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Extract(ICollection`1 jars, ICollection`1 resolvedResourceDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedAssetDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedEnvironments)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() MyTunes.Droid
```

How to resolve these warnings?

Comment: What Android SDKs did you install? There are multiple, one for each major release. Open your project properties and see that API levels you are targeting and match it with the SDK versions you have installed.

Comment: I believe I have everything greater than API 15 installed, and I'm not targeting apps lower than 15..

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to Nuget Package Manager by right click on project. And click on installed tab and then click on select all checkbox and then update all.

Then build again

Comment: I'm not able to update packages, it starts but after some time fails due some errors

Comment: Don't update all the packages. Only update Xamarin.Forms. The Xamarin.Android.Support.* libraries should not be updated.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and leave a comment if it helped